# How to override a Bootstrap plugin definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make some adjustments (actually, fixes) to the Bootstrap 3 Button plugin, but I can't wait for the whole submit code/pull request/approval process.  I also don't want to make any edits directly to the bootstrap.js file.  I thought I could add another file called bootstrap-override.js which loads after bootstrap.js and contained another copy of the Buttons plugin code with my customizations, but this isn't working.  The code from the original Buttons plugin fires.

What is the correct pattern for replacing an already defined plugin like this:

```
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: button.js v3.3.0
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */


+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // BUTTON PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
  // ==============================

  var Button = function (element, options) {
    this.$element  = $(element)
    this.options   = $.extend({}, Button.DEFAULTS, options)
    this.isLoading = false
  }

  Button.VERSION  = '3.3.0'

  Button.DEFAULTS = {
    loadingText: 'loading...'
  }

  Button.prototype.setState = function (state) {
    var d    = 'disabled'
    var $el  = this.$element
    var val  = $el.is('input') ? 'val' : 'html'
    var data = $el.data()

    state = state + 'Text'

    if (data.resetText == null) $el.data('resetText', $el[val]())

    // push to event loop to allow forms to submit
    setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
      $el[val](data[state] == null ? this.options[state] : data[state])

      if (state == 'loadingText') {
        this.isLoading = true
        $el.addClass(d).attr(d, d)
      } else if (this.isLoading) {
        this.isLoading = false
        $el.removeClass(d).removeAttr(d)
      }
    }, this), 0)
  }

  Button.prototype.toggle = function () {
    var changed = true
    var $parent = this.$element.closest('[data-toggle="buttons"]')

    if ($parent.length) {
      var $input = this.$element.find('input')
      if ($input.prop('type') == 'radio') {
        if ($input.prop('checked') && this.$element.hasClass('active')) changed = false
        else $parent.find('.active').removeClass('active')
      }
      if (changed) $input.prop('checked', !this.$element.hasClass('active')).trigger('change')
    } else {
      this.$element.attr('aria-pressed', !this.$element.hasClass('active'))
    }

    if (changed) this.$element.toggleClass('active')
  }


  // BUTTON PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ========================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.button')
      var options = typeof option == 'object' && option

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.button', (data = new Button(this, options)))

      if (option == 'toggle') data.toggle()
      else if (option) data.setState(option)
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.button

  $.fn.button             = Plugin
  $.fn.button.Constructor = Button


  // BUTTON NO CONFLICT
  // ==================

  $.fn.button.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.button = old
    return this
  }


  // BUTTON DATA-API
  // ===============

  $(document)
    .on('click.bs.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^="button"]', function (e) {
      var $btn = $(e.target)
      if (!$btn.hasClass('btn')) $btn = $btn.closest('.btn')
      Plugin.call($btn, 'toggle')
      e.preventDefault()
    })
    .on('focus.bs.button.data-api blur.bs.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^="button"]', function (e) {
      $(e.target).closest('.btn').toggleClass('focus', e.type == 'focus')
    })

}(jQuery);
```

Comment: I think you need a `.off` for each of the `.on`s

Comment: The code posted is the 3.3.0 Bootstrap code from GitHub, not my own version.

Comment: Wait, sorry.  I think I misunderstood your comment.  Do you mean to use .off() to unbind the event? I still remember the old unbind() so it took me a minute to get what you were saying.  Let me try that...

Comment: @cvrebert, that worked, thanks!  If you resubmit it as a proper answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Curious what the "fixes" you mention are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the original Bootstrap button plugin's event handlers using [`jQuery.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/). You need to `.off()` each of the original button plugin's `.on()`s. Example:

```
$('document').off('click.bs.button.data-api focus.bs.button.data-api blur.bs.button.data-api');
```